# MySQL and PHP Order Addresses by first letter, not numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I've made a MySQL database for a real estate company, and have it functioning and displaying results. Now I am trying to get the results to show up in ASC order, but when written,

```
`$query="SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY Address ASC"; `
```

it sorts by the number in the address, so 100 Zebra Street comes before 200 Apple Way, which I expected. But my desired result is for the query to sort by the first letter in the street name.

Is there an easy way to achieve this, or should I just separate the fields so one column is the number, and the next column is the street name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you separate the columns if possible. If you intend to work on parts of the address, then logically you should break it up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be achieved.  The solution is outlined here:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/3011288/order-by-letters-and-not-numbers-of-a-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011288/order-by-letters-and-not-numbers-of-a-field)

Although it's more practical & efficient to split it into multiple columns.